# VBA Search row changed and code needs update

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a code that I am now using to automatically insert numbers to a cell that has todays date on Column A and the correct name on the first row of that column.

However, I can't seem to make it work if the names are in any other row than 1.

What changes do I need to make if I want it to search matches on row 2 or multiple rows?

```
Sub SyöttöEriVälilehti()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo M
Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim col As Long
col = 0
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim DateLastrow As Long
Dim ans As String
Dim LString As String
Dim LArray() As String
Dim anss As String
Dim ansss As String

With Sheets("Malli2Data") ' Sheet name
    DateLastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = .Range("A1:A" & DateLastrow).Find(Date)
    If SearchRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox Date & "  No matches", , "Oops!": Exit Sub
    Lastrow = SearchRange.Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ans = InputBox("Input name and number like so:  Tom,5")
    LString = ans
    LArray = Split(LString, ",")
    anss = LArray(0)
    ansss = LArray(1)

    For i = 2 To LastColumn
        If .Cells(1, i).Value = anss Then col = Cells(1, i).Column
    Next

    If col = 0 Then MsgBox anss & " No matches": Exit Sub

    .Cells(Lastrow, col).Value = ansss
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
M:
MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine _
& "Check input" & _
vbNewLine & "You typedt: " & ans & vbNewLine & "Correct input type: " & vbNewLine & "Name" & ",Number" & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Try again"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet:

```
For i = 2 To LastColumn
    If .Cells(1, i).Value = CDec(anss) Then col = Cells(1, i).Column
Next
```

Is searching row 1 for your name

If you want to change it and make it a variable, something like

```
For i = 2 To LastColumn
    If .Cells(xRow, i).Value = CDec(anss) Then col = Cells(1, i).Column 
Next
```

With xRow being your defined row to search will work.

At the same time, you could sub out the last bit within the loop and use

```
For i = 2 To LastColumn
    If .Cells(xRow, i).Value = CDec(anss) Then col = i
Next
```

As they are the same thing.

edit 20201-04-23A: Use of CDec(anss) will convert the string (as gathered from "ans") into a decimal number - which can then be compared against the .Value taken out of the cell.

Comment: Hi, and thank you! I am new to VBA and have some trouble still, can't figure out the correct way to input the search row. Tried 2, and 2:2 and still got error.

Comment: Did you try: xRow = 2

Comment: Hi, I did but it returns "no matches", this is what I am using now.
   xRow = 2
    For i = 2 To LastColumn
        If .Cells(xRow, i).Value = anss Then col = i  'xRow määrittelee hakurivin
    Next

Comment: OK, realised what we've missed now. Your comparing a string (anss) to a value. Will edit original answer to rectify.